# zf2 get userid logged into the system in the Model

Tags: zend-framework2

I am using ZF2
I am want to get the user information who has logged into the system. Basically I am having a create_userid and last_update_userid for every table. I want to populate this with the id of the user who has logged in and performing the operations.

I can pass this as a parameter into my operations from the controller; I would like to get this automatically from the system.

I am sure someone else would have thought about this and performed this.

Comment: Authentication helper and controller plugin is what you're looking for: https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.authentication.intro.html

Comment: @foozy I am not talking about getting the user information in the controller. I need this information in the web talk about passing the user information into the model to perform an audit trail.

Comment: The Table is a stand alone class; is it good to inject the user info into the class like the way we inject the TableGateway using the service manager. What are the pitfalls of such an approach.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found when a class is created to implement ServiceLocatorAwareInterface we can do all sorts of things with the service locator. Also, the servicelocator is set automatically by the MVC engine.

I created the Table to implement ServiceLocatorAwareInterface and I could get the user id of the logged in user.

I have the code below

```
namespace UserAdmin\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class UserTable implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {

    protected $serviceLocator = null;
    protected $loggedUser = 0;
    protected $tableGateway;
    protected $table = "user";

    public function __construct( TableGateway $tableGateway ) {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator() {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

    protected function setLoggedUser( ) {
        $serviceLocator = $this->getServiceLocator( );
        $authService = $serviceLocator->get( 'AuthService' );
        if ( $authService->hasIdentity( ) ) {
            $this->loggedUser = $authService->getIdentity( )->user_id;
        }
    }

...
...
    public function saveUser ( User $user ) {

        if ( $this->loggedUser == 0 ) {
            $this->setLoggedUser( );
        }
...
...
        $data [ 'last_update_userid' ] = $this->loggedUser;
        $data [ 'last_update_timestamp' ] = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );

        if ( is_null( $user_id ) ) {
            $data [ 'create_userid' ] = $this->loggedUser;
            $data [ 'create_timestamp' ] = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
            $this->tableGateway->insert( $data );
        } else {
            if ( $this->getUser ( $user_id ) ) {
                $this->tableGateway->update( $data, array ( 'user_id' => $user_id,  ) );
            } else {
                throw new \Exception ( "Could not find row in table $this->table  for update" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This takes care of most of my needs. There is just two aspects.

a> I tried calling the setLoggedUser function from the constructor and it does not work. I think the service locator is set after the entire construction. so I am calling the function just before a save, and that is when I need it. Is this a clean implementation or is there another way to do this.

b> An User can register himself on the site; and the userid is an autogenerated sequence so how do I populate the userid to be the same as the new userid.

Two things come to my mind;
1> After insert read the user record and update the record with the userid
2> Not worry about this so much and have a system superadmin id as the id to write users who self register.

This is a problem only for self registrations of users only. Any other table within the system will be inserted or updated only after the user is logged in.

Comment: `Not worry about this so much and have a system superadmin id as the id to write users who self register.` seems about right.

Comment: But it is always a good practice to just set the `create_userid` from the Controller when you do the `exchangeArray()` so that the `User $user` object will have it. Don't go for including the `serviceLocator` in the User Table class for such a small thing.

Comment: @KunalDethe does this hamper the performance? right now, my controllers have no idea about the audit columns

Comment: When you call the `setLoggedUser()` from the controller it does not have the `serviceLocator` set. What you need to do is inject the `$sm`  from the Module.php similar to how `tableGateway` is injected. Please check the new answer.

Comment: Yes, the `serviceLocator` being assigned to the Table class does have a problem. It just gives the Table a full access to all the services. The whole concept of `Dependency Injection` is lost. You can never have a clear picture of how much the Table class is dependent upon other classes / services.

Answer (score 0):

To set the Service Locator in the UserTable Class -

In UserAdmin/Module.php -

```
'UserAdmin\Model\UserTable' => function($sm) {
    $tableGateway = $sm->get('UserTableGateway');
    $table = new UserTable($tableGateway);

    //This way the serviceLocator is injected to the Table.
    $table->setServiceLocator($sm); 

    return $table;
},
```

Now, when you will call the `setLoggedUser` from the controller, the value will be set.

**Important:**
Rather than having the above private function, the best approach will be to have a Controller Plugin. This plugin will check if any user is logged in or not and if yes then return the user's id.

Comment: Thanks Kunal, Infact making the Table class to implement ServiceLocatorInterface; the framework injects this directly. Is the automatic setting not better?